# send id (or get id from router path)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I got simple blog (react/redux) (only frontend part). With user registration and articles. And stuck when tryed to send id to editor. I have same form, but different path for add new and for edit existing article:

```
<Route path="/add" component={ !currentUser ? Login : ArticleEditor } />
<Route path="/article/:id/edit" component={ !currentUser ? Login : ArticleEditor } />
```

it might be simple but I have no idea how to send(or get) id to ArticleEditor component to fill form.
Plz help if you have good knowledge in React/Redux.

here is the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-resonance-d9tu6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use useParams

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
```

```
  const { id } = useParams();
```

or in class component

```
const id = this.props.match.params.id;
```

Comment: ty. looks like I can't use hooks inside class component. :( should i rewrite all to functions or is there another way to got id?

Comment: to class component             try ``const id = this.props.match.params.id;``
in constctor

Comment: tnx. tried this, and now it seems its another problem in my code, cos its always 'undefined'. will searh for mistake.